# Python KivyMD Changing Interface after building app in smartphone

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I want to compile my KivyMD application using buildozer. Before doing this, I run the application on the computer and see one interface. But after I collect it through buildozer, I see a completely different interface on my phone, and I don’t know what this is connected with. Please help, work is on fire...

Comment: Start by looking for `kv` files that may (or may not) be getting loaded. Consult the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv).

Comment: There is no clear structuring of the project yet, I have only one main.kv file